# Get HttpClient's generated url

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

If I have a pointer to a HttpClient's get observable, is it somehow (via internal variables etc.) possible to get its request url?

I'd like to use its generated query without reinventing the wheel. I know this is probably not the cleanes solution but pretty ok in my scenario, where I already have generated services for my REST API and just would like to generate a download link.

Answer (score 0):

There are some overloads from the Angular HttpClient that return an `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>` as long as you call the `HttpClient#get` overload that has the `observe` parameter set to `"response"`. [See here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

[image]

If you check [the documentation about Angular HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) you can see it has a `url` property and perhaps contains what you need to know

Comment: Yes, thank you! But in this case I'd need to call the request. I'd prefer to not even call it. Any idea?

Comment: You could, for instance, provide a wrapper to the HttpClient and inject it into the DI, something like `providers: [{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: MyHttpClient }]` in your module. Then in your `export class MyHttpClient extends HttpClient` just read whatever parameters are relevant for you and forward the request to `super.get<T>()` or any other methods?

Comment: Sounds like a solution approach, too. But my API module is a root provided service (generated by swagger codegen). So I cannot modify / replace any of it's dependencies for one use case. But the information needed must be wrapped somehow in this observable, isn't it?

Comment: Well, with an NPM task you can just replace the HttpClient for that module as well. Assuming you already have a npm task such as `npm run codegen` you can create another one that does just "search and replace" inside the swagger `api.module.ts` after you're done codegening and make your codegen look like `"codegen": "{codegen-command} && npm run inject-custom-http-client-in-api-module"`

While you just keep calling `super.http_verb<T>` at the end of the day you'd be good to go.

Comment: That'd be another good solution, yes. Thank you! How do you like mine? And suggestions for it?

Comment: I don't know what you're attempting to do; question mentioned how to get the generated URL from an `Observable` returned from the HttpClient and in your answer below you're cancelling requests rather than checking what the URL was; I am a little confused 

Comment: My interceptor caches the request that _should_ have been executed without actually running it. This way my method can get the HttpRequest without executing it. Do you like the idea? Any improvements?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the HttpClient's code a bit and in it's promise a HttpRequest gets created. There is no way to get the properties but by getting this object. So I solved this with an interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class CancelRequestHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    static current: CancelRequestHttpInterceptor;

    constructor() { CancelRequestHttpInterceptor.current = this; }

    isActive = false;
    intercepted = new Subject<HttpRequest<any>>();

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.isActive) { this.intercepted.next(request); return EMPTY; }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

and in the component I do

```
try {
    let request: HttpRequest<any>;
    CancelRequestHttpInterceptor.current.isActive = true;
    CancelRequestHttpInterceptor.current.intercepted.pipe(first()).subscribe(v => request = v);
    this._reportService.exportReport(here, goes, my, params).subscribe();

    alert(request.urlWithParams);
}
finally {
    CancelRequestHttpInterceptor.current.isActive = false;
}
```

I guess, since JS runs single threaded, this solution is ok?

**But**: why am I using a static variable and no DI (that I'd prefer)? Because in my feature loaded module I cannot resolve the HttpInterceptor! I'm going to create a new question and link it here.

Any improvements here?

Comment: Here the promised link to my DI issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241523/not-able-to-resolve-httpinterceptors-in-feature-module