# Not able to resolve HttpInterceptors in feature module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

When trying to get the registered HttpInterceptors in a feature loaded module (`@Inject(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) interceptors: HttpInterceptor[],`) I just get an array with one interceptor registered: **HttpXsrfInterceptor**.

When doing the same in the AppModule I get all the interceptors available. What is causing my issue? I'd like to set some interceptor properties by some modules.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors must be provided into the same Module which import HttpClientModule.
It might explain why it only works in your AppModule.